# logstash-output-clickhouse throws error while installing plugin

Tags: java, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

```
Validating logstash-output-clickhouse-0.1.0.gem
Installing logstash-output-clickhouse
Plugin version conflict, aborting
ERROR: Installation Aborted, message: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "logstash-mixin-http_client":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    logstash-mixin-http_client (= 6.0.1)

  In Gemfile:
    logstash-filter-http java was resolved to 1.0.2, which depends on
      logstash-mixin-http_client (>= 5.0.0, < 9.0.0) java

    logstash-input-http_poller java was resolved to 4.0.5, which depends on
      logstash-mixin-http_client (>= 6.0.0, < 7.0.0) java

    logstash-output-clickhouse (= 0.1.0) java was resolved to 0.1.0, which depends on
      logstash-mixin-http_client (>= 2.2.1, < 6.0.0) java

    logstash-output-http java was resolved to 5.2.4, which depends on
      logstash-mixin-http_client (>= 6.0.0, < 8.0.0) java

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

I'm trying to install logstash-output-clickhouse-0.1.0.gem on Centos. And I'm getting this error when I try to install the plugin using the below command.

```
bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-output-clickhouse-0.1.0.gem
```

**Can anyone please explain what version needs to be upgrade or downgrade.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install an older version of logstash. Currently your clickhouse plugin requires the http_client mixin to be less than 6.0.0, whilst the http output and http filter require the http_client mixin to be greater than or equal to 6.0.0.

Comment: I am using logstash 6.8. Should I downgrade to 5?

Comment: You could try that. I do not know all the version dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using .gem file, you can use.
`./logstash-plugin install logstash-output-clickhouse`